# How do I find the tag associated with a commit as part of a github pull-request action?

Tags: github, continuous-integration

I've got this step:

```
- name: getSumac
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: yma/sumac
    ref: ${{ github.ref }}
```

That works when the action is triggered by pushing a tag. But when a PR is created or updated, `github.ref` is something like `refs/pull/99/merge` and the `getSumac` step fails.

On the command-line, I would run something like `$( git describe --tags | grep -Eo '^v[.0-9]+' )` to get the most recent tag. Is there a way to do that in a github action step?

Comment: Would it be possible to create the PR on the git tag itself? That might give you the actual tag name with the github.ref.

Comment: No need -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in this case I could set a `VERSION` env var, so I could do something like this:

```
steps:
- name: Override the VERSION env var
  run: |
    VERSION=${VERSION:-$(git describe --tags | sed 's/^v//')}
    if [ -n "$VERSION" ] ; then
      echo "VERSION=$VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    fi
```

And the actions I'm using just use `$GITHUB_ENV` (I never reference it explicitly in the other steps).